# zsh crash when starting inside tmux with `zsh-newuser-install: startup files exist, aborting`

Tags: linux, zsh, tmux

Every time I try to start `zsh` inside of `tmux` it crashes wwith

```
zsh-newuser-install:  startup files exist, aborting
```

It worked flawless yesterday night, and suddenly this morning nothing works...

I'm starting tmux with this line as the first in `.zshrc`:

```
if [ "$TMUX" = "" ]; then tmux; fi
```

Thanks!

My `zshrc` file:
https://github.com/Richard87/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template

## **EDIT**

It suddenly started working again... I don't know what changed, or what is wrong... **scratch that, it stopped working again**

## EDIT #2

On the same computer, it works for root user, but not my main user (the .zshrc files are exactly the same, the only different is that my own user have a custom tmux config file:

```
# set Zsh as your default Tmux shell
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh

# Tmux should be pretty, we need 256 color for that
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"


# Tmux uses a 'control key', let's set it to 'Ctrl-a'
# Reason: 'Ctrl-a' is easier to reach than 'Ctrl-b'
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b

# command delay? We don't want that, make it short
set -sg escape-time 1

# Set the numbering of windows to go from 1 instead
# of 0 - silly programmers :|
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1


# Allow us to reload our Tmux configuration while
# using Tmux
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

# Getting interesting now, we use the vertical and horizontal
# symbols to split the screen
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I got the same problem today.

Comment: Nope, not yet 

Comment: How about now gus? I have the same problem today.

Comment: Just had this problem myself, any solution for you?

Comment: Sorry, the only solution I have is disabling tmux or zsh (I hose tmux)

Comment: Interesting I have a similar issue but with visual studio code. So far I wasn't able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 11):

This happens to me when, after booting, I open the terminal inside IntelliJ before opening a standalone terminal:

- If I open the standalone terminal first, both the standalone and IntelliJ's terminals work well.
- If I open IntelliJ's terminal first, both the the standalone and IntelliJ's terminals fail showing this message: `zsh-newuser-install:  startup files exist, aborting`.

The only workaround I've found to this is:

1. Close all the terminals and open a standalone terminal, the message should not be shown, then **while this one is open**, open the IntelliJ terminal and the problem won't happen anymore.
2. In some cases that hasn't worked because I opened the standalone terminal first. In that case, I do what @rghamilton3 suggests: `tmux kill-server` and then do #1 again.

Comment: For Intellij users running into the issue described above, here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46696447/559119

Comment: Yes this works, and all started because I tried to use a terminal plugin in sublime. Closing all open terminals and reopening fixed everything

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but I seen newer comments on it and I just had this happen to me. I just killed the server by running `tmux kill-server` and surprisingly enough that did fixed it for me. YMMV of course but hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

First, the zsh-newuser-install function **should** only be run if:

1) The user does not have any personal zsh startup files(like .zshrc)

2) If the following lines appear in your .zshrc file:

```
autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install
zsh-newuser-install -f
```

3) If the same commands are run manually.

I would check your .zshrc file just in case. Hopefully this will give you a place to start looking.

Personally I wouldn't put the tmux command in the first line of the .zshrc file, but that is my personal opinion. I believe using the `TMUX` variable is not the best choice for determining if tmux is already running. You would have to be starting a shell running in a tmux window/pane for the variable `TMUX` to be set. The results of `tmux ls` would be a better choice in my opinion.

```
Var=("${(f)$(tmux ls)}")
[ ${#Var} -eq 0 ] && tmux
```

As I don't know your use case, you may not choose this method.

Comment: This does not solve my problem, since there are *no* lines like yours in my zshrc file :/